# Capture create event in Outlook calendar

Tags: vba, events, outlook, calendar

I am trying to capture the event, when one is creating a new calendar entry directly within Outlook's work week view (*not* using "New Appointment" button).

What's working is to capture the event fired through the "New Appointment" button with this code:

```
Dim WithEvents colInsp As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set colInsp = Application.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub colInsp_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Inspector)
    If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olAppointment Then
       Set oAppt = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub oAppt_Write(cancel As Boolean)
' Do something
End Sub
```

The newInspector sub doesn't get called when creating an event directly in the weeks view.

What is the correct approach for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Calendar folder returned from `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)`.

Answer (score 1):

Dimitry, thank you. With this I found the following:

```
Private WithEvents colItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set colItems = oFolder.Items

    Set oNS = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Sub

Sub colItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    ' Do what's needed
End Sub
```

Source: http://microsoft.public.office.developer.outlook.vba.narkive.com/6zlusiPe/new-calendar-item-is-created